# functions as javascript object properties

Tags: javascript

What is the difference - if there is a difference - between functions ex1() and ex2()? Does the way of defining fun1 inside the body of ex1 have benefits over the way of defining in ex2?

```
    function ex1() { 
    var fun1 = function () { return 0; };
    var x = fun1();
}

function ex2() { 
    function fun1() { return 0; }
    var x = fun1();
}
```

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the question

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: It's a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/497418 really.